# Pytesseract: White list dosent work properly

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract, whitelist

I've been trying to use the withe list to print just numbers from an image, but it still printing text.

```
nums = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config='--psm 3 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
```

I've also tried other variants, but it had not worked too.
Any idea?

Comment: maybe you set this option in wrong way. If you tried other options then you should show it - we can't read in your mind.

Comment: using Google I found that some versions may not have this option: [Blacklist and whitelist unsupported with LSTM (4.0) · Issue #751 · tesseract-ocr/tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/751)

Comment: BTW: as I remeber this option is NOT for filtering data and display only numbers but to inform OCR that it has to treat all chars as numbers - i.e. it should recognize `g` as `9` . If you have some text with numbers then you should cut off image and use only part with numbers, or you should get all text and later search numbers in this text using i.e `regex`